# How to run a method of a fragment from an activity, using Tags?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment, onresume

I've got a little app in which I created three swipeable tabs using eclipse. One of these is a common fragment while the second and third are ListFragments each of them gets it's data from a Cursor.

I experiment with it and wanted to delete the content of the database, which is created in the onCreate of the hosting activity. My problem is, when I delete the data, the second tab, one of the ListFragments, is not updated while the third tab is.

As the second gets updated, when i put the phone into sleep an reawake it, i think, the second tab is not moved into its lifecycle, so it does not call onResume.

Both ListFragments use the same code to update:

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updateList();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    }

public void updateList(){
        dbCursor.requery();
        dbAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i(TAG, "updateList");
    }
```

So I tried to do it with the onTabSelected method but I always got a NullPointerException which I want to avoid by using tags but I don't get it working.

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
        switch(tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            MenueFragment menu = new MenueFragment();
//          fragmentTransaction.add(menu, "1");//Eclipse wants to change Type of menu from MenueFragment to Fragment
//          menu = (MenueFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("1"); //My latest, not working approach...
            menu.updateList(); //In this Fragment updateList only does an entry into LogCat for testing.
            break;
        case 1: //These two following cases show how I tried it before.
            GefilterteListe fragment = new GefilterteListe();
            fragment.updateList(); 
            break;
        case 2:
            GesamteListe fragment2 = new GesamteListe();
            fragment2.updateList();
            break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onTabSelected");
    }
```

Eclipse always wants to change the types of my Fragments to an other Fragment-class and wants the android.app.fragment while I want to use the support.v4...

How do I get it working, so that both ListFragments are refreshed?
Im brand new to Fragments and I know that the Cursor-class is depreciated but I didn't yet have the time to understand Loaders... :/

**Edit:** Here is my not working ListFragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GefilterteListe extends ListFragment{

    public static final String TAG = GefilterteListe.class.getSimpleName(); 

    private DatenbankHandler dbHandler;
    private Cursor dbCursor;
    private LehrerDatenbankAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i(TAG, "GefilterteListe onCreate");
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan, container, false);
        return returnView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHandler = new DatenbankHandler(getActivity());
        dbCursor = dbHandler.queryFilter();
        dbAdapter = new LehrerDatenbankAdapter(getActivity(), dbCursor);
        setListAdapter(dbAdapter);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updateList();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        updateList();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
    }*/

    public void updateList(){
        dbCursor.requery();
        dbAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i(TAG, "updateList");
    }

}
```

Its almost identical to the working one, besides the name and that the other one uses queryAll() instead of queryFilter().

My other Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenueFragment extends Fragment {


    public static final String TAG = MenueFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView text;
    Button button;
    DatenbankHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MenueFragment onCreate");
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        text = (TextView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        button = (Button) returnView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text.setText("Datenbank gelöscht.");
                dbHandler = new DatenbankHandler(getActivity());
                dbHandler.redoTbl();
            }

        });

        return returnView;
    }

    public void updateList(){
        Log.i(TAG, "updateList nonsense");
    }
 }
```

<s>The activity is mostly the same, as Eclipse created it. I only added my Fragments.</s> 
**Edit2:** Here is my hosting activity:

```
public class HostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private static final String TAG = HostActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private DatenbankHandler dbHandler;

    private MenueFragment menueFragment;
    private GefilterteListe gefilterteListe;
    private GesamteListe gesamteListe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      passwort("okidoki"); //Passwort Dialog
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menueFragment = new MenueFragment();
        gefilterteListe = new GefilterteListe();
        gesamteListe = new GesamteListe();

        dbHandler = new DatenbankHandler(this);
        dbHandler.redoTbl();
        dbHandler.insert("T", "E", "S", "T", "This is a ", "Test.");
        dbHandler.insert("E", "E", "S", "T", "This is a ", "Test.");
        dbHandler.insert("S", "E", "S", "T", "This is a ", "Test.");
        dbHandler.insert("T ", "E", "S", "T", "This is a", "Test.");

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.host, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        /*Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
        switch(tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            MenueFragment menu = new MenueFragment();
//          fragmentTransaction.add(menu, "1");//Eclipse wants to change Type of menu from MenueFragment to Fragment
//          menu = (MenueFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("1"); //My latest, not working approach...
            menu.updateList();
            break;
        case 1:
            GefilterteListe fragment = new GefilterteListe();
            fragment.updateList();
            break;
        case 2:
            GesamteListe fragment2 = new GesamteListe();
            fragment2.updateList();
            break;
        }*/
//      updateAll();
        Log.i(TAG, "onTabSelected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment frag = new Fragment();
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                MenueFragment menu = new MenueFragment();
                frag = menu;
                break;
            case 1:
                Fragment fragment = new GefilterteListe();
                frag = fragment;
                break;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragment2 = new GesamteListe();
                frag = fragment2;
                break;
            }
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void updateAll() {       
        menueFragment.updateList();
        gefilterteListe.updateList();
        gesamteListe.updateList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you place here some snippets of your fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
interface DBchangesListener {
    public void updateList();
}
```

Then your fragments:

```
public class MenueFragment extends Fragment implements DBchangesListener {...}
public class GefilterteListe extends Fragment implements DBchangesListener {...}
public class GesamteListe extends Fragment implements DBchangesListener {...}
```

In activity put:

```
private MenueFragment menueFragment;
private GefilterteListe gefilterteListe;
private DBchangesListener gesamteListe;
```

and then in  `onCreate()` :

```
menueFragment = new MenueFragment();
gefilterteListe = new GefilterteListe();
gesamteListe = new GesamteListe();
```

Add your fragments like you add it right now. 
Next create simple method in your activity:

```
public void updateAll() {
    menueFragment.updateList();
    gefilterteListe.updateList();
    gesamteListe.updateList();
}
```

At the end of your DB changes just invoke `updateAll()` to update all of your fragments.

Comment: Thanks but sadly I don't get it working.  I created a new Interface like in your example (never used it before) and implemented it in my fragments.  
Are you sure that I should do it like this: `private DBchangesListener gesamteListe;`? GesamteListe is one of my fragments, too. Anyway, I tried both.  
The onCreate thing is clear to me.  
I put the updateAll() once in the onTabSelected and another time in the onTabUnselected. Both doesn't work.  
Waht am I doing wrong? Also, I added my hosting activity, to get you a better idea of it.

Comment: Addition: I put the updateAll() into the MenueFragment first, as the database is deleted there and also put it in both mentioned onTab(Un)Selected.

Comment: I wonder why you're using fragments instead of activities. Maybe try to change your classes into activities instead of fragments

Comment: This is because I wanted the tabs to be swipeable and used the Assistant to create them. The few examples I found were also done with Fragments. But I'll try it when I retunr home.

Comment: So, I tried it, but sadly it doesn't seem to work with activitys. Or at least, I'm not clever enough to get it working... :/